# Unity WheelCollider - relation between brakeTorque and brakeDistance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics

So I am trying to write an AI for learning purposes and I am facing one (one of the many to come) problem that whenever the car approaches an intersection or a turn it has to slow down to a set speed of lets say 30km/hr.

I know how to slow it down by using brakeTorque but what I am trying to do is calculate the distance at which I start applying the brakeTorque according to the current velocity of the car so that it reaches to desired speed at the intersection. ( I know I can apply excessive brake torque within a set distance and maintain by observing the speed but that will cause very erratic and uneven braking and I want some smooth braking). So this question is more like physics coding question.

(Please dont suggest applying a force to the rigidbody. This is for learning purposes and I want to achieve it through brakeTorque only. Also, the wheelcolliders friction values are set as such they will not slip easily both sideways and forward both direction)